# Three logos on Beamer

Tags: beamer, logos

I have my presentation finished but I need to add the logos of my schools and it is giving me problems. For my presentation I am using the following:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\normalsize\ttfamily, breaklines=true, framextopmargin=10pt, framexbottommargin=10pt, frame=single, breakindent=0pt}
\usepackage{color}
\usetheme{Dresden}
\usecolortheme{seagull}
\definecolor{cream}{RGB}{255,255,221}
\definecolor{light}{rgb}{0.88,1.0,1.0}
\definecolor{melon}{rgb}{1.0, 0.94, 0.84}
\definecolor{bisque}{rgb}{0.69,0.93,0.93}
\definecolor{amarillo}{rgb}{0.94, 0.92, 0.84}



\title{Title.}
\date{Date}
\author[]{Author}
```

and I need to put 3 logos as shown in the following image
[image]

I have tried to look for solutions but none have worked for me and I am still not very skilled using tikz, can someone give me a clue on how to arrange my logos?

Comment: Please don't post code fragments. Always add a small, but compilable test file which includes an actual document body.

Comment: You should say if you want the logos on the title page only, or on any page, or any combination of that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use the `textpos` package:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[absolute,overlay]{textpos} % Needed for absolute positioning
\usepackage{graphicx} % Needed for including graphics

% Theme settings
\usetheme{Dresden}
\usecolortheme{seagull}

% Title and author information
\title{Title.}
\date{Date}
\author[]{Author}

% Begin document
\begin{document}

% Title page frame
{
% Disable navigation symbols for the title page
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}

\begin{frame}
  % Actual content of the title page
  \titlepage
  
  % Logo placeholders using textblocks
  \begin{textblock*}{5cm}(1cm,0.5cm) % {block width} (coords)
    \centering
    Logo 1 Placeholder
  \end{textblock*}
  
  \begin{textblock*}{5cm}(6.5cm,0.5cm) % {block width} (coords)
    \centering
    Logo 2 Placeholder
  \end{textblock*}
  
  % Move Logo 3 to the bottom left
  \begin{textblock*}{5cm}(1cm,8.5cm) % {block width} (coords)
    \centering
    Logo 3 Placeholder
  \end{textblock*}
  
\end{frame}
}

% Rest of your presentation
% ...

% End document
\end{document}
```

To insert the image:

```
\begin{textblock*}{5cm}(1cm,0.5cm) % {block width} (coords)
  \centering
  \includegraphics[width=4cm]{path/to/logo1.png} % Adjust the width as needed
\end{textblock*}
```

[image]

Comment: And to insert the images is it done in the normal way?

Comment: Edited answer to include image

Comment: It worked perfectly for me, thank you very much

Answer (score 4):

You could use tikz to conveniently place your logos without having to guess coordinates (adjust `outer sep=...` to change the distance from the corners):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{dsfont}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{listings}
\lstset{basicstyle=\normalsize\ttfamily, breaklines=true, framextopmargin=10pt, framexbottommargin=10pt, frame=single, breakindent=0pt}
\usepackage{color}
\usetheme{Dresden}
\usecolortheme{seagull}
\definecolor{cream}{RGB}{255,255,221}
\definecolor{light}{rgb}{0.88,1.0,1.0}
\definecolor{melon}{rgb}{1.0, 0.94, 0.84}
\definecolor{bisque}{rgb}{0.69,0.93,0.93}
\definecolor{amarillo}{rgb}{0.94, 0.92, 0.84}



\title{Title.}
\date{Date}
\author[]{Author}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\maketitle
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay,remember picture,outer xsep=0.5cm,outer ysep=1cm]
\node[anchor=north west] at (current page.north west) {\includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{example-image-duck}};
\node[anchor=north east] at (current page.north east) {\includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{example-image-duck}};
\node[anchor=south west] at (current page.south west) {\includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{example-image-duck}};
\node[anchor=south east] at (current page.south east) {\includegraphics[width=1.5cm]{example-image-duck}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]